# "XAMPP: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly" after restarting PC

Tags: mariadb

I'm having a trouble with starting XAMPP MySQL, due to restarting my PC without stopping the MySQL service. Everytime I'm trying to start it I'm getting this:
[image]

Here's the exact log:

```
2023-06-20  2:06:12 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 8732
2023-06-20  2:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-06-20  2:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-06-20  2:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-06-20  2:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-06-20  2:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-06-20  2:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2023-06-20  2:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-06-20  2:06:12 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=132539175
2023-06-20  2:06:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 5 pages from redo log.
2023-06-20  2:06:13 0 [ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Trying to read page number 49153 in space 0, space name innodb_system, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384Please check that the configuration matches the InnoDB system tablespace location (ibdata files)
230620  2:06:13 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision: c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=65537
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 20302 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler()
ucrtbase.dll!raise()
ucrtbase.dll!abort()
mysqld.exe!??$_Construct@$00PEBD@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEAAXQEBD_K@Z()
mysqld.exe!?_Assign_grow@?$_Hash_vec@V?$allocator@V?$_List_unchecked_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@U?$pair@QEAU_iobuf@@PEAX@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAX_KV?$_List_unchecked_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@U?$pair@QEAU_iobuf@@PEAX@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?_Assign_grow@?$_Hash_vec@V?$allocator@V?$_List_unchecked_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@U?$pair@QEAU_iobuf@@PEAX@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAX_KV?$_List_unchecked_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@U?$pair@QEAU_iobuf@@PEAX@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?_Assign_grow@?$_Hash_vec@V?$allocator@V?$_List_unchecked_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@U?$pair@QEAU_iobuf@@PEAX@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAX_KV?$_List_unchecked_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@U?$pair@QEAU_iobuf@@PEAX@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@@Z()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!?_Assign_grow@?$_Hash_vec@V?$allocator@V?$_List_unchecked_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@U?$pair@QEAU_iobuf@@PEAX@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAX_KV?$_List_unchecked_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@U?$pair@QEAU_iobuf@@PEAX@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?_Assign_grow@?$_Hash_vec@V?$allocator@V?$_List_unchecked_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@U?$pair@QEAU_iobuf@@PEAX@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAX_KV?$_List_unchecked_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@U?$pair@QEAU_iobuf@@PEAX@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?_Assign_grow@?$_Hash_vec@V?$allocator@V?$_List_unchecked_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@U?$pair@QEAU_iobuf@@PEAX@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@@std@@QEAAX_KV?$_List_unchecked_iterator@V?$_List_val@U?$_List_simple_types@U?$pair@QEAU_iobuf@@PEAX@std@@@std@@@std@@@2@@Z()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!pthread_dummy()
mysqld.exe!?_Xlen_string@std@@YAXXZ()
mysqld.exe!?ha_initialize_handlerton@@YAHPEAUst_plugin_int@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPEAHPEAPEADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPEAHPEAPEADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?init_net_server_extension@@YAXPEAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?win_main@@YAHHPEAPEAD@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_service@@YAXPEAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysqld_main@@YAHHPEAPEAD@Z()
mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
The manual page at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/how-to-produce-a-full-stack-trace-for-mysqld/ contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
Writing a core file at C:\xampp\mysql\data\
Minidump written to C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysqld.dmp
```

---

**Here's what I've tried doing:**

- Restarting my PC again and again
- Deleting/renaming *aria_log.00000001* and *aria_log_control* from C:\xampp\mysql\data
- Using cmd I tried `\bin\aria_chk -r mysql\*.MAI` that "repaired the files, but it still won't start.
- Adding "innodb_force_recovery = 1" and "innodb_force_recovery = 2" to my.ini and restarting mySQL
- deleting ibdata1 and any other file in /data folder, which just completely resets an entire Wordpress site to the blank one (i made a copy to ibdata1 before deleting it)

I'm really running out of ideas at this point, is there any chance of restoring my website at this point? I have only a local copy which was not uploaded anywhere yet, I was just working on it from my PC...

**Edit**: I know this question was asked here countless times, but I've tried most of the solutions from StackOverflow and nothing seems to work. Maybe the logs will give you an idea what's going on?

Comment: I'm going to have a fucking metal breakdown! That's the second time it happened to me and I've put around 40-50 hours into this second version of the website. I really gotta take a break from all this...

Comment: I was deleting files from /data folder one by one trying to run MySQL and restoring them all back. After I deleted b_logfile0 without touching anything else MySQL has managed to run and I can go, view and edit my website. I just need to make a copy of it at this point, OMG. I hope I'll be able to save it after all!

Comment: If you check out the error message, you can see there is nothing we can do from a programming point of view. If something similar happanad to you more than once on the same computer, then you beed to check your computer.

Comment: Understood. As I told you in my previous message - I was able to run the site by deleting the b_logfile0. Everything looks and works as before. However, I'm not sure if I'll be able to get back there again. I'll just try to copy/save as much data as I can at this point and use it as a reference when making another version of this site, when already on proper hosting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup of your MySQL folder, you can restore it to fix the "MySQL shutdown unexpectedly" error. By doing so, you will replace the damaged or corrupt files with backups.

To restore your MySQL backup folder, follow these steps

1. Close the XAMPP web server completely. Navigate to the location where XAMPP is installed after you've closed the web server. XAMPP is located by default at "C:\xampp."
2. Open the “mysql” folder. Locate the “data” folder and rename it to “data_old” to store the old files in a safe way. This step is crucial to make sure you have a backup.
3. After that, right-click anywhere in the directory and select New > Folder from the context menu to create a new folder. Give the newly created folder the name “data”.
4. After you've created the new data folder, open the “backup” folder. Copy the backup folder's contents and paste them into the newly created “data” folder.
5. Now that you've completed all of this, run XAMPP as an administrator. Try running the MySQL server once the XAMPP Control Panel is open to see whether the problem persists.

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I did, since that's the most popular solution to this error. Unfortunately, nothing changed after doing so...